# Fraud detection by the payment processor using IP address

Tags: web-services, architecture, payment-gateway, payment-processing

We have two web applications that process payments using a payment processor. One web application is used by the customer service and the other one by a customer on the internet. When a payment needs to be processed the ip address of the client is sent in the payload to the payment processor. The payment processor has fraud detection rules enabled where if multiple payment calls are made from single ip then the ip is blocked. Now, when the customer service app makes the payment calls, they will send multiple calls for payment with the ip address of the system that the rep is using. This is causing an issue with the payment processor. We cannot disable the fraud rules because we need it for the customer app and the payment processor is not in our control. We dont want to whitelist few ips that rep is using as the rep can connect from home too. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the payment processor's capabilities. I suspect the payment processor can accept payments from the server, rather than directly client. If that's the case, you can have admins submit to the server, and have the server submit to the payment processor. You can now whitelist the server without regard to where the clients are coming from.

Comment: As mentioned, you're depending on the features of the payment processor. If you don't control it and you cannot change its implementation, you're limited by its existing feature set.

Ideally, you'd want the payment processor to support an authentication system and have your customer service reps (CSRs) use it to gain access to the processor. Then you'd want to configure the processor to apply different fraud detection rules to the CSR requests than to the customer ones. But all of this depends on the payment processor.